# Does plasma have viscosity like a real fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, plasma-physics

[Fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid) is a substance that continually deforms (flows) under an applied shear stress, or external force. Fluids are a phase of matter and include liquids, gases & [plasmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)). My question: Does [plasma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)) have viscosity like a real fluid & why or why not?

Comment: Because it does flow? You seem to answer the question in the body, so I'm a bit unclear as to the actual question.

Comment: Well, in the limit of no ionisation, plasmas become ideal gases which do have a (ballistic) viscosity. I know nothing about the viscosities of sensible plasmas though.

Comment: The plasmas in space only have viscosity in the fluid sense where you take the mean free path times the thermal speed and mass density (i.e., coefficient of viscosity).  This is effectively meaningless though because the solar wind is not collisionally mediated.  In truth, the viscosity of the solar wind can be treated as zero or near zero.  The only thing limiting shear flow is typically the orientation of the magnetic field.